# Effect of sampling frequency to the center of a bandbass filter

Tags: sampling, frequency-response

Is it true that if you have some sort of filter, e.g. a digital bandpass filter around the frequency 1000 Hz that is given in the form of a transfer function $H(z)$ and you then change the sampling frequency of the input that the same filter can suddenly have its "center" (of the bandpass) at another frequency?

Which keyword can I look up to learn more about this concept?

Comment: Well, yes, because for digital signal processing, the actual sampling frequency is unbeknownst to the filter - it just is a sequence of numbers to be convolved with the sequence of numbers that is your signal. Thus, there's nothing special to google - you'd simply read up on the basics of discrete signal theory.Since your profile says you're living in Munich,I assume you've got access to German-language libraries–I personally do like the (Jäkel/Kiencke/Puente) "Signale und Systeme" book that I was taught with,and it will pretty clearly explain how Nyquist rate,sampling rate&z-transform relate.

Comment: @MarcusMüller comment already says everything but for clarity, a digital filter's cutoff frequency in hertz in by essence relative to the sampling frequency, also in hertz. Generally, we use a normalised axis for spectrums where the frequency axis is f/Fs (the units cancel). [This forum post](https://www.dsprelated.com/showthread/comp.dsp/53840-1.php) has some interesting answers, and [this blog article](http://blog.prosig.com/2013/06/04/a-guide-to-digital-filtering/) can also help you